# Using Jquery to make a drag and drop game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am working on a project that I need to create a drag and drop game.
I have multiple items that need to be dropped and one drop area. 
And the drag item will be deleted once being dropped to the drop area.
However, I am not able to think of a way to identify which item I am dragging and dropped, which is important for the game to continue.

Here is the code I made so far.

```
 var backpack =[];
 var backpackLength;
```

```
  $( function() {
  $( "#item1" ).draggable();
  $( "#bag" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
        backpack.push("item1");
        backpackLength++;
        $("#item1").remove();
        alert(backpack);
        alert(backpackLength);
          if(backpackLength > 0){
            document.getElementById("bag").src = "minigame/bag2.png";
          }
          if(backpackLength > 4){
              document.getElementById("bag").src = "minigame/bag3.png";
          }
      }
    });
  } );
```

I got stuck here for so long, I have no idea how to change the value of "item1" into other items so that it will identify them...
Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but check out the `this` keyword. I use it when manipulating tables and determining which row I have selected. You may be able to use it to tell which `#item` you have chosen. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: Thanks! I am so new to this, thanks for the suggestion, I will check it out!